# Convert InputStream to Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to read a file contents and emit a flow for every line of its contents. So, I have to implement a function with the following signature:

```kotlin
fun InputStream.linesToFlow(): Flow<String>
```

Is there any way to implement this function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the following solution as well:

```kotlin
fun InputStream.linesToFlow() = bufferedReader().lineSequence().asFlow().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Comment: You might want to add `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` at the end to make sure it does not accidentally block some useful thread.

Comment: I saw this recommendation in the kotlin slack as well. But I would like to write a better reasoning for this. Can you describe why this is needed to have it here as documentation?

Comment: Create a scratch project and try running code from this gist: https://gist.github.com/elizarov/311b646c2fbf5fe19768fac3f21fe109 
Now, add `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` and see what difference does it make.

Comment: @RomanElizarov I ran the gist with the .flowOn and saw no difference. What was I supposed to see? Also, it seems the .flowOn is critical as it puts the flow on a separate (IO) thread taking if off the main thread. If I have this wrong, please provide a link for me to study and get it right. And finally, what is the purpose of the yield()? Is this simply to get back to the main (original) thread?

Answer (score -2):

You can do this

```
fun InputStream.linesToFlow(): Flow<String> = channelFlow<String> {
    reader().forEachLine { line -> 
        offer(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: It will drop lines when the collector is slow. Take some text file and see what happens if you do `File("text.txt").inputStream().use { it.linesToFlow { line -> println(line); delay(1000) } }` (the correct solution should print a line of the fine every second)